# Splash screen on iPhone4 shifts

Tags: ios, splash-screen, ios4

I am working on an iOS app and for some reasons the splash screen shifts a few pixels up or stretches ( it's hard to tell) upon start up.
This is only happening on my iPhone 4 devices. I noticed that if I set my app to fullScreen (no status bar on top on the phone for battery life etc), there is no shifting.

Also, no issues on iPhone 5.

I've checked the image size of my Default.png splash screen and they are 640 x 960.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post a screenshot or two?

Comment: Are you saying that you have a splash screen that matches your apps background (in your xib file) and it is shifting or are you saying that while the Default.png is showing it shifts...

Comment: Your Default.png shouldn't shift at all... if it matches something behind it in the xib it might give the allusion of a jump.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. Please see the comments below. Any ideas on that?

Answer (score 0):

To do this right, you really should have more than one Default file:

`Default.png` (320 x 480) for support of the original iPhone thru iPhone 3GS

`Default@2x.png` (640 x 960) for support of the iPhone 4 and 4S

`Default-568h@2x.png` (640 x 1136) for support of the iPhone 5

Trying to use one Default for all different sized screens might technically work, but you certainly won't get the best quality.

Comment: Hi Axeva,

Thanks for your reply.
I had the following and
Default.png set at (640 x 960)
Default-568h@2x.png (640 x 1136)

Interestingly, I now renamed Default@2x.png (640 x 960) and added a new Default.png (320 x 480).

I find that on my iPod 4, there is no shift anymore but it picks up the Default.png as opposed to the Default@2x.png like I would have expected. How does that make sense? 

The shifting has gone though! :)

Comment: Glad to hear the picture no longer shifts.  Not sure why the iPod isn't picking up the @2x file though.  Double-check that the capitalization of the file name is right, that it's 72 dpi, and the resolution is 640 x 960

Comment: As far as I can see, resolution and dpi are as expected for the @2x file. Odd. But thanks anyway, I might just go with this current work around. For now anyway :)